# App showing for one user but not others

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an C# ASP app called babyapp that's configured on a remote box and under the following structure:

```
   -IIS
   --Live
   ---Application Pools
   ----Web Sites
   -----motherapp
   ------babyapp
```

Now the issue:

I can access this app on my local machine via IE at http://motherapp/babyapp however other users can't.

Any initial thoughts? Is it something that's maybe hard-coded in the applications files  (cs, asp or webconfigs) or is it something as simple as IIS settings?

For the users that cannot see the app the page that's returned is this: 
[babyapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9WXf.png)

Any initial thoughts? Is it something that's maybe hard-coded in the applications files  (cs, asp or webconfigs) or is it something as simple as IIS settings?

Comment: The first url returns a 404 page not found for me and if i go the homepage it works perfectly fine

Comment: Have you checked the event logs/IIS logs on your box to see what is being logged for these attempts?

Comment: I'll happy accept that as answer Paddy! I check the logs and it showed why a NotAuthenticated.aspx is thrown for the users not working. And it is thrown because a hard code in master page which says: 

string sSQL = "SELECT * " +
                " FROM dbo.tbl_users " +
                " WHERE employeeID = " + "'" + userNtLogin + "'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = DBConnectViewpoint.DataReaderDataTable(sSQL);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[0]["groupNameBabyApp"].ToString() != "babyAppAdministrator")

Comment: {
                    Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthenticated.aspx",true);
                }
                if (dt.Rows[0]["groupNameBabyApp"].ToString() == "babyAppAdministrator")
              else
     { //do what you want! ;-) 
     }

Comment: Added the users in the db now who I need to have to access to it. As you can tell I am a newish dev but this is a new skills now to add to my toolbox. ;-)